# Get value of ListView item in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I am filling my `ListView` with data which I am getting from the database I created. I want to get the name of the item in `ListView` which is being long clicked. 
I have tried using following method:

```
 - parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
 - myListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
 - myListView.getSeletedItem(position).toString();
```

These three statements work well but as I am filling up the `LisView` by getting data from my database so I am getting the following value returned:

> 09-20 13:01:22.370: I/System.out(5351): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@426925b0

whereas the Item's name, which I am clicking, is 'Home'..

Please help me. How can I convert `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@426925b0` into `Home`?

**MY ADAPTER:**

```
mCursor = mDB.fetchData();
String[] columns = new String[] { AreaDatabase.KEY_AREA };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvArea };

    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.lvarea, mCursor,
            columns, to);
    lvArea.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

**fetchData() function:**

```
public Cursor fetchAreaData() {
    Cursor mCursor = ourDatabase.query(AREA_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
            KEY_ROWID, KEY_AREA }, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    return mCursor;
}
```

Comment: @ Adeel Shahzad ........ Welcome to Stackoverflow ....... post the code properly formatted and what you have tried so far .... so that we can help you faster ..... !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cursor` has method `getString(int columnIndex)`. You can use that to get `String` value from `Cursor` from specified column index.

```
> Cursor currentCur = myListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
> String name = currentCur.getString(1); //It will return KEY_AREA (column index 1) value from Cursor
```

Comment: Works well for the first entry in ListView. But getting this error for 2nd entry in ListView<br/>
`09-20 13:41:21.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8396): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col 2 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
`

Comment: Can you provide the code when u call getString() method?

Comment: Are you using position as columnIndex? You shouldn't. position is more like position of the row of Cursor instead of the column. So you just call getString(1); for every item

Comment: I apologize for a silly mistake I was making. I was calling the getString() method and passing `position + 1` as the parameter. I called the method again by passing the column index which contains the values and got the correct answer. Appreciate your quick help, mate.

Answer (score 0):

do like this :

```
parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

Comment: Still getting the same result